# nvidia-driver-390 version stuck at 138

Tags: apt, nvidia, graphics

After updating to kernel `5.4.0-60`, somehow nvidia kernel modules got updated to `390.141`, while even after `apt update`, some components (most importantly `nvidia-kernel-common-390`) got stuck at `390.138`.

This obviously created issues, leading to nvidia-driver not loading because of version mismatch.

I tried to use `additional-drivers` to fix the issue, but even after changing the driver to nouveau and then back to 390, I had no luck. Also `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` did not work (because of the version issue). Another thing I tried was to remove all nvidia component using apt, then reinstalling them, which also failed, even after I changed my apt repository to the Main one (instead of the local mirror)

A fix can be to use `390.141` components for everything, but currently neither apt nor additional-drivers do that. I guess it might also be possible to uninstall `390.141` kernel modules and make everything 138, but I really don't like this solution, as there are known security vulnerabilities with the `390.138` driver.

Is there any other solution besides manually installing nvidia-driver?

BTW, I have a `GT-440` card and 390 is the latest major version that supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used official graphics PPA to get the new drivers.

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```